# v2.ODataModel: Response object (response headers) not contained in the "requestCompleted" event

Tags: odata, sapui5, xsodata

I have an OData V2 model bound to a `sap.m.Table`. The trigger for the service call (to HANA XSOData) is through the `bindAggregation` method. I have attached the `requestCompleted` method to get the `statistics` back from the server to add to the UI.

However, when I check the event linked to `requestCompleted`, I don't see the response headers in the object. The response object doesn't match what's in the documentation.

Below is the [`requestCompleted` documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23events/requestCompleted) (Using SAPUI5 version 1.84.26):

[image: SAPUI5 API reference requestCompleted]

Below is my return object for the `requestCompleted` method. The **`"response"` and `"headers"` are missing from the event parameters.**

[image: requestCompleted Event object object in my app]

I have checked the OData call in network and the response header I need is being returned correctly:

[image: Screenshot of my OData response]

Am I missing something in OData call to UI5? How do I access the response headers in the `requestCompleted` event? I tried to read through the `oSource` object as well but couldn't find it there either.